# Exposing a simple struct using Rust FFI

Tags: memory-management, rust, ffi

I am trying to expose a simple struct via FFI. Is this the best way to do it?

I am not 100% sure about the get_text function. This is taking the string out of the struct and cloning it before returning a pointer to it. I suspect this is going to leak. Whats the best idiomatic way around this? Do I need to provide a free_string function? Is there a way to just return a pointer into the Rust string?

```
﻿use std::mem;
use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_void};
use std::ffi;


#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SomeData {
    text : String,
    number : usize,
}


#[no_mangle]
/// Make the structure. Box it to stick on the heap and return a pointer to it.
/// This absolves Rust from having to deal with the memory, so it is the callers
/// responsibility to free it by calling drop_data.
pub extern "C" fn make_some_data (text: *const c_char, number: usize) -> *mut c_void {
    let cstr = unsafe {
        assert!(!text.is_null());
        ffi::CStr::from_ptr(text)
    };

    let data = cstr.to_str().ok().map(|utf8_str| {
        Box::into_raw(Box::new(SomeData {
            text: String::from(utf8_str),
            number,
        }))
    }).unwrap();

    data as *mut c_void
}

#[no_mangle]
/// Returns the text field of the struct.
pub extern "C" fn get_text(data: *mut c_void) -> *mut c_char {
    let data = unsafe {
        assert!(!data.is_null());
        Box::from_raw(data as *mut SomeData)
    };
    let text = data.text.clone();
    mem::forget(data);
    ffi::CString::new(text).unwrap().into_raw()
}

#[no_mangle]
/// Returns the number field of the struct.
pub extern "C" fn get_number(data: *mut c_void) -> usize {
    let data = unsafe {
        assert!(!data.is_null());
        Box::from_raw(data as *mut SomeData)
    };
    let number = data.number;
    mem::forget(data);
    number
}

#[no_mangle]
/// Frees the memory.
pub extern "C" fn drop_data (data: *mut c_void) {
   mem::drop(data); 
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to check rust binaries with valgrind?

Comment: @422_unprocessable_entity BTW yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509672/7076153

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should always run clippy:

```
error: this public function dereferences a raw pointer but is not marked `unsafe`
  --> src/lib.rs:20:29
   |
20 |         ffi::CStr::from_ptr(text)
   |                             ^^^^
   |
   = note: #[deny(clippy::not_unsafe_ptr_arg_deref)] on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#not_unsafe_ptr_arg_deref

error: calls to `std::mem::drop` with a value that implements Copy. Dropping a copy leaves the original intact.
  --> src/lib.rs:60:4
   |
60 |    mem::drop(data); 
   |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[deny(clippy::drop_copy)] on by default
note: argument has type *mut std::ffi::c_void
  --> src/lib.rs:60:14
   |
60 |    mem::drop(data); 
   |              ^^^^
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#drop_copy
```

`drop(data)` is indeed totally useless here pointer don't have drop implementation, you must use `Box::from_raw(data as *mut SomeData)` (BTW you didn't check for null here hope this is what you want). I also advise you to mark these function as `unsafe`.

For the style there is two sides as you seem to require the pointer is no null:

- You could assume the pointer is always no null, add only a debug panic
- You could panic if the pointer is null

I'm in favor of the first option but it's as you like, if you take the second option I advice to use `Option<&T>` this will prevent you to forget to check if the pointer is null, it's guarantee by Rust that `Option<&c_char>` will be `None` for null pointer value.

Your `get_number()` and `get_text()` use `Box::from_raw(data as *mut SomeData)` for nothing, just use directly the pointer or transform it to reference.

I'm unsure `void` pointer is necessary.

> Do I need to provide a free_string function? Is there a way to just return a pointer into the Rust string?

yes of course you must use [`from_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.from_raw)

Final code:

```rust
use std::ffi;
use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_void};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SomeData {
    text: String,
    number: usize,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn make_some_data(text: Option<*const c_char>, number: usize) -> *mut c_void {
    ffi::CStr::from_ptr(text.unwrap())
        .to_str()
        .map(|str| {
            Box::into_raw(Box::new(SomeData {
                text: str.to_string(),
                number,
            }))
        })
        .unwrap() as *mut c_void
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn get_text(data: Option<&c_void>) -> *mut c_char {
    let data = my_real_data(data);
    ffi::CString::new(data.text.clone()).unwrap().into_raw()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn get_number(data: Option<&c_void>) -> usize {
    let data = my_real_data(data);
    data.number
}

unsafe fn my_real_data(data: Option<&c_void>) -> &SomeData {
    &*(data.unwrap() as *const std::ffi::c_void as *const SomeData)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn drop_data(data: Option<*mut c_void>) {
    Box::from_raw(data.unwrap() as *mut SomeData);
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn drop_text(data: Option<*mut c_char>) {
    ffi::CString::from_raw(data.unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, very useful. I'm a little unclear about what you mean re Option. Are you suggesting the function parameter as `fn get_text(data: Option<*const c_void>)` instead of `fn get_text(data: *mut c_void)`?

Comment: I think you mean `data: Option<&mut c_char>` instead of `Option<*mut c_char>` as the parameters to `drop_data` and `drop_text`? It compiles but crashes as you have it written there..

Comment: @MongusPong Please show the code that make it crash.

Comment: It was the code as you had written here. The data was being passed in as None and so the unwrap was panicking.